# Apache and required modules and configuration for Wordpress

Tags: php, apache, configuration, server

- I'm not familiar with server configuration, I have tried to deploy a site with  a person working on server but not going so well.

After moving the source files + database, everything works fine except the theme options

- When I try to re-save it, it just keeps loading (I think there a problem with /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php)
- When I try to update a page, I got "you don't have permission to access /wp-admin/post.php on this server)

What we have tried:

- Set www-data owner to all files in /wp-admin
- set right permission 644 for files / 755 for all folders.
- Set AllowOverride All

Nothing working for me. Is there any source that can list all apache, php and required modules and configuration a bit more detail so that I can provide to the people on the server?

Thank you very much

Comment: From my experience, there could be some configuration mismatch between the old environment and new one. It does not necessarily be apache configuration. IIRC, the domain configuration or path configuration might as well be the culprit. Check the domain configuration in wp-config.php and configurations stored in database (the wp_xxx_options table; to make it easier, search for the old domain in the meta_value field).

Comment: @Wiguno because we currently have a live site working 
ex: naomibakery.com

so when I deploy the new site, I have changed its domain name to exact naomibakery.com, but using host file to redirect to the IP server to test it, could that be the problem that you mentioned?

Thank you very very much for the answering.

Comment: Actually, no. It is okay to test to the new production server by defaulting the IP address in your hosts file. I do that all the time before updating the domain DNS record. What I meant was it is possible that this is due to different server environment. For example, on old server, the path to theme was `/var/www/wp-content/themes/theme1`, but this changes in the new server to `/var/www2/wp-content/themes/theme1`. Since some of the themes do store the configuration in the database, this path mismatch might bring some unwanted errors.